# Reactjs: Issue while updating context API shared by multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-component, react-context

In my react application, I have login page and dashboard. I want to display username, fetched from login page to dashboard using context API.

Following is my App.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Login from './Login'


import {UserContextProvider} from './context/UserContextManagement'
const DashboardPage = () => (<Dashboard />);

const LoginPage = () => (<Login />);

function App() {
  return (
    
      <Router>
      <UserContextProvider>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
        
        </UserContextProvider>
      
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Following is my Login.js Code:

```
import {UserContext} from '../../context/UserContextManagement'

function Login() {

const {setUsernm}=React.useContext(UserContext);

        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        window.location = '/dashboard';
      }


  return (
    <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" onChange={e => {setUsernm(e.target.value)}}/>
          <input type="text" onChange={e => setPwd(e.target.value)} />
          <button type="submit">Sign In </button>
        </form>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Following is my UserContextManagement:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

//Customised Provider
export const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [usernm, setUsernm] = useState("invalid"); //Due to Usestate, value is resetted
 
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ usernm: usernm, setUsernm: setUsernm }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Issue: I am able to update username by using `setUsernm` in login.js file but since both login.js and dashboard.js is route in App.js using same `UserContextProvider`. `UserContextProvider` is executed again while redirecting from login to dashboard and due to `useState` initialization, `usernm` is reset to state default i.e. invalid.

How to define useState in such a way that username is not reset to state default value?

Comment: `useState` doesn't reset the value because it is only initialized to that value one time when the application loads initially, since it is in the Context. It should work as you are intending if your app isn't reloading. Maybe it's something in your `Dashboard.js` that is causing the error. By the way, naming your username variable `usernm` is bad practice. You should just name it `username`. It doesn't help anything to name it `usernm` and it makes your code harder to read. Abbreviating things like this is generally a bad idea. It's better to have readable code than to save two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see your login component as well because [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-leavitt-siy49?file=/src/App.js) seems to be working as intended ?

Maybe your app is reloading so the context is lost ?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-leavitt-siy49?file=/src/App.js)

To redirect you should use react-router-dom functions.

Your login should ressemble that :

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
function Login() {
   let history = useHistory()
   let {setUsername} = useContext(UserContext)

   function handleSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     // Do the things you need
     history.push('/dashboard')
   }
   return (
   <div>
       <form>
         <input type="text" onChange={e => {setUsername(e.target.value)}}/>
         <input type="password" onChange={e => setPwd(e.target.value)} /> // Use password type
         <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)>Sign In </button> // Probably gonna need to attach the function to onClick
       </form>
     </div>
   );
}
```

[Documentation in React-Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Comment: I have edited my question and added login.js code. May you please help me out?

Comment: You were right my app was reloading so the context was lost. I have fixed it. Thank you very much. Also, I had edited my login.js code. Let me know if there is better way to redirect from submit event handler. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: I edited to include how to push to another page/url @Purva If you watch my codesandbox, you'll also notice a few things. You don't need to `usernm: usernm` you just need `usernm`. You should also name it `username` so it's easier to read. We have autocomplete anyway so it's not a big deal to write more :) You also don't need to create function to pass your components to the Route. When imported it's already a component so you can just pass it (or do what I did in codesandbox)